# Overflow working on chrome/android but not in IE/Firefox

Tags: css

When rendered in Chrome/Android the website shows as intended but in IE/Firefox some vertical scrollbars appear. Simplified code:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu, .slide, .ico {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar, .slide::-webkit-scrollbar, .ico::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    }

.links {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML structure**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<div class="container">
<div class="links">
```

I hope I copied the sufficient code to show the issue. If needed I can link the website.

The idea is having the links div be scroll-able vertically but without showing the scrolling bar.

**Edit:** here is the full code: http://www.jcml.pt

**Edit2**: I was able to fix it (but created another problem as can be seen on my answer).

Comment: where is the scroll bars appearing?

Comment: I've added a link to the website.

Answer (score 0):

well...

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

Means if content overflows in y axis (vertical), show a scroll bar. It sounds like this is what your seeing. And that this code worked! (lol)

Try adjusting the `height:` of the element (or parent element) where this is occurring it may need a few more pixels of space in IE or Firefox to show all of the content in vertical space; as browsers render / read slightly differently *(especially if defined as 100% or auto)*.

Then remove `overflow-y: scroll;` leave it blank or declare `overflow-y: auto;` or if your still having an issue trying define your `height` in pixels or declare a `max-height:` with the `100%` if your *still* having issues please try to update your question so we can fully understand and provide a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo and / or screenshot.

Comment: I used .menu::-webkit-scrollbar, .slide::-webkit-scrollbar, .ico::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;} to remove the scrollbar since it looks like a more elegant solution than making the element bigger *some* pixels. So I guess this only works for chrome and android?

Answer (score -1):

Since it was working on Chrome I thought I was going on the right direction and searched even more things and found this scheme:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx

I was able to fix it the problem by creating two containers instead of one (but now it doesn't scroll at all - something I'll have to work on later). Code can be seen here: http://www.jcml.pt/3

Comment: Why are people just down voting everything instead of telling me what I'm doing wrong? That's not the way you should welcome members and increase the quality of their posts...